# SOQL Inner Join Query

Tags: soql

I am just wondering if I could write a SOQL query for this:

- Find list of `Lead`

  - That have an open `Task` assigned to specific `User` and
  - Where the `Lead.CreatedDate` equals the `Task.CreatedDate`?

Comment: are you willing to do this in apex?

Comment: You realize the `CreatedDate` fields are actually of type `Datetime` and hence extremely unlikely to collide?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to add some architecture you can enable this with a simple checkbox on `Lead` called something along the lines of `Has_Task_Created_Same_Day__c`. Then you would write a `Task` trigger or *maybe* use `Process Builder` to build a flow. That trigger or flow would just have to look at records created by your special `User` with a `WhatId` corresponds to a `Lead`, and see if the `Lead.CreatedDate` was today.

If you want it now, you can't accomplish what you want with pure `SOQL`; you will need to do some post-processing. You can find all relevant `Task` records and generate a `Map<Id, Set<Date>>` corresponding to the`CreatedDate` values (`Date` part only). Once you have that you can compare with your `Lead` records.

Here is some untested code to give you the gist:

```
static final User SPECIAL_USER; // lazy load someone via query
public static List<Lead> getSomeLeadSubset()
{
    List<Lead> subset = new List<Lead>();
    Map<Id, Set<Date>> taskIdToCreatedDates = getTaskCreatedDates(getLeadIdsWithTask());
    for (Lead lead : [
        SELECT CreatedDate FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :taskIdToCreatedDates.keySet()
    ]){
        Set<Date> taskCreatedDates = new Set<Date>();
        if (taskCreatedDates != null && taskCreatedDates.contains(lead.CreatedDate.date()))
            subset.add(lead);
    }
    return subset;
}
public static Set<Id> getLeadIdsWithSpecialUserTask()
{
    Set<Id> leadIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
        SELECT WhatId FROM Task WHERE What.Type = 'Lead'
        AND OwnerId = :SPECIAL_USER.Id GROUP BY WhatId
    ]){
        leadIds.add(aggregate.get('WhatId'));
    }
    return leadIds;
}
public static Map<Id, Set<Date>> getTaskCreatedDates(Set<Id> leadIds)
{
    Map<Id, Set<Date>> taskIdToCreatedDates = new Map<Id, Set<Date>>();
    for (Task task : [SELECT WhatId, CreatedDate FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :leadIds])
    {
        if (!taskIdToCreatedDates.containsKey(task.WhatId))
            taskIdToCreatedDates.put(task.WhatId, new Set<Date>());
        taskIdToCreatedDates.get(task.WhatId).add(task.CreatedDate.date());
    }
    return taskIdToCreatedDates;
}
```